# adding to lists together using cbind

Tags: r

This program works because I made the varibles inisde lapply global by using the <<- operator.  However, it does not work with the real files in the real program. These are .tsv files whith named columns.  The answer I get when I run the real program is: Error: (converted from warning) Error in : (converted from warning) Error in : arguments imply differing number of rows: 3455, 4319.  What might be causing this?

```
lc <- list("test.txt", "test.txt", "test.txt", "test.txt")
lc1 <- list("test.txt", "test.txt", "test.txt")
lc2 <- list("test.txt", "test.txt")
#list of lists.  The lists contain file names
lc <- list(lc, lc1, lc2) 
#new names for the three lists in the list of lists
new_dataFns <- list("name1", "name2", "name3")
file_paths <- NULL
new_path <- NULL
#add the file names to the path and read and merge the contents of each list in the list of lists
lapply(
  lc, 
  function(lc) {
    filenames <- file.path(getwd(), lc)
    dataList <<- lapply(filenames, function (lc) read.table(file=lc, header=TRUE))
    dataList <<- lapply(dataList, function(dataList) {merge(as.data.frame(dataList),as.data.frame(dataList))})

  }
)  

#add the new name of the file to the path total will be 3 paths/fille_newname.tsv.  
lapply(new_dataFns, function(new_dataFns) {new_path <<- file.path(getwd(), new_dataFns)})

print(new_path)
print(dataList)

finalFiles <- merge(as.data.frame(dataList), as.data.frame(new_path))
print(finalFiles)
```

Comment: You have to tidy your code up. As it is now, it doesn't even run, there are syntax errors (unmatched braces etc.). Also, it isn't obvious what's the first and what's the second program. The commented out code I suppose isn't relevant to the question, so it should be removed here, so your question code is more readable.

As for the answer, it looks to me on a first glance that the problem is that R's `*apply` functions are side-effect free, so the `dataList` and `new_path` are going to be `NULL` even after the `lapply`, although you didn't say *how* the code fails.

Comment: How can I edit the post?

Comment: You can use the [edit] link under the question.

Comment: I was able to make the variables inside lapply by ussing the <<- operator.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem by writing a different type of code.  Please see below.  The input to the function is provided by the app input widgets

```
glyCount1 <- function(answer = NULL, fileChoice = NULL, combination = NULL, enteredValue = NULL, nameList) {
  lc = nameList


  new_dataFns <- gsub(" ", "", nameList)
  first_path <- NULL
  new_path <- NULL
  old_path <- NULL
  file_content <- NULL
   for(i in 1:length(lc)){
      for(j in 1:length(lc[[i]])){
         if(!is.null(lc[[i]])){
              first_path[[j]]<- paste(getwd(), "/", lc[[i]][j], sep = "")
              tryCatch(file_content[[j]] <- read.csv(file = first_path[[i]], header = TRUE, sep = ","), error = function(e) NULL)
              old_path[[j]] <- paste(getwd(), "/", i, ".csv", sep = "")
              write.table(file_content[[j]], file = old_path[[j]],  append = TRUE, col.names = FALSE)
         }

      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.